# how to use friends.getAppUsers

Tags: c#, facebook

I am new to `friends.getAppUsers` and I am not sure how to use this. 
I want to search all my friends that have been  registered to my website.
Please explain me in detail how to implement this and this will be great help.

Thanks
Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of your friends with the following Graph Query:

```
SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

You would then cross reference that list of `uid` from people that you have stored in your database (with single sign-on or what-not).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this

```
FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'select name from user  where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'
        }, function(response){});
```